# Error while trying to run script with atom

Tags: python, numpy, pycharm, atom-editor

I'm trying to run script like below in atom (or in pycharm)

```
import numpy as np
def bar(num_elems):
    restrained_dofs = 0

    m = np.array([[2,1], [1,2]]) / (6. * num_elems)
    k = np.array([[1,-1],[-1,1]]) * num_elems

    M = np.zeros((num_elems+1,num_elems+1))
    K = np.zeros((num_elems+1,num_elems+1))

    for i in range(num_elems):
        M_temp = np.zeros((num_elems+1,num_elems+1))
        K_temp = np.zeros((num_elems+1,num_elems+1))
        M_temp[i:i+2,i:i+2] = m
        K_temp[i:i+2,i:i+2] = k
        M += M_temp
        K += K_temp

    for dof in range(restrained_dofs):
        for i in [0,1]:
            M = np.delete(M, dof, axis=i)
            K = np.delete(K, dof, axis=i)


bar(1)
```

and I recive following terminal output

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/Programowanie/Python/bar_elem.py", line 1, in <module>
    import numpy as np
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\numpy\__init__.py", line 142, in <module>
    from . import add_newdocs
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\numpy\add_newdocs.py", line 13, in <module>
    from numpy.lib import add_newdoc
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from .type_check import *
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\type_check.py", line 11, in <module>
    import numpy.core.numeric as _nx
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\__init__.py", line 35, in <module>
    from . import _internal  # for freeze programs
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\_internal.py", line 12, in <module>
    from numpy.compat import basestring, unicode
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\numpy\compat\__init__.py", line 14, in <module>
    from . import py3k
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\numpy\compat\py3k.py", line 14, in <module>
    from pathlib import Path
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\pathlib.py", line 13, in <module>
    from urllib.parse import quote_from_bytes as urlquote_from_bytes
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\urllib\parse.py", line 597, in <module>
    _asciire = re.compile('([\x00-\x7f]+)')
AttributeError: module 're' has no attribute 'compile'
```

But the same script is working correctly while using *Spyder3* or in Terminal.
I'm running script wit *Script* packacge in Atom, but other packages gives the same result.
Python 3.7.1, 
Numpy 1.15.4

Comment: The script README suggest running Atom from the Terminal for full access to your environmental variables. Have you tried that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that the script was placed in a folder named *Python*, after moving it to another location everything works fine